# LibreCalc 7.6.4 Menu and Toolbar

Tags: libreoffice

Just downloaded LibreOffice 7.6.4 and I have created a quick access bar.   This shows up on the right side of the top menu bar. How do I make into a floating toolbar or a docked toolbar,  always on show in the ribbon?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "toolbar" in the "Standard Toolbar" UI interface...

Unfortunately, it seems that only certain, but not all, toolbars stay from session to session (meaning closing LO and reopening, I would call them *static* from here on out) in LO. It seems that non-context dependent toolbars could be *static*, but exactly which one would require you to do some testing.

Also, toolbar display in LO applications are independent from one another, meaning what's shown in Calc can be different from Writer. In addition, some are considered *static* toolbar in an application may **not** be *static* in another application. For example, `formatting` can be *static* in Writer, but not *static* in Draw.

Here are toolbars are static in most applications (Writer, Calc, Impress, Draw):

- Standard (but it depends on the usage mode, such View-only)
- Find
- Drawing

Therefore, your best bet is: find a *static* toolbar that you don't foresee using yourself, and then customize it to your needs in the specific application.